OpenCV Hue channel blur
I've created process that do some tricks on image to look better. One of the steps is to blur hue channel from HSV image. To blur channel I'm using cv::blur.
The problem is that hue is circular, so in some cases when i have 0 and 179 values, blur is giving results around 40-80.
I've tried to use Lab, but does not work as good as it works with HSV.
How can I do cv::bulr on hue channel and keep its circular form?

Compute a=S*cos(H) and b=S*sin(H), blur those two channels, then compute H back from result. Though HSV is is not really useful for image processing, it was designed to let a user pick a color.

@CrisLuengo Cris, could you consider writing this up as a proper answer please?

looks like a YUV type would be more suitable. the UV plane is the same plane that hue and saturation span (give or take).

A smoothing filter such as cv::blur is a (weighted) mean operation. To compute the mean of angles, the common approach is to instead average unit vectors with the given angle. That is, we convert each value phi into the pair (cos(phi),sin(phi), average the pairs, and then compute the angle of the result (using atan2 to preserve the quadrant)
We can do the same thing when blurring an image that encodes angles, such as the hue channel of an HSV image. Simply compute the two images a=cos(H) and b=sin(H), blur each image, and finally compute H=atan2(b,a) with those blurred images.
In HSV, pixels with a zero saturation have a meaningless hue. When the saturation is low, the hue is less precise. It should also be less important in the averaging. So, we can weight the averages with S. To do so, compute a=S*cos(H) and b=S*sin(H). The remainder stays the same.

But do note that HSV is not really suitable for image processing. HSV was originally designed to allow a user to pick a color in a GUI, in a drawing program. Other color spaces are more suitable. You could use, for example, CIE Yxy, where Y is the luminance and xy are the two chromaticity components. Yxy is a linear version of Lab, and doesn’t attempt to be perceptually uniform. The x and y channels can be simply blurred (the angle between the two is comparable to H and the norm is comparable to S). CIE Lab, CIE Luv, OKLab, etc could also be good color spaces to work in, depending on what the purpose of the processing is. All of these separate luminance (intensity, brightness, what have you) from chromaticity.

Thank you for writing it all up so thoroughly.

@MarkSetchell Only because you asked so nicely. :)

Than you @CrisLuengo for a great answer and @MarkSetchell for leading to this answer. Blurring Hue channel with above solution works great. Also, I've tried to use XYZ color space (CIE XYZ) and this works with my code, so I will use it instead of blurring Hue.

@Raffallo XYZ is just a rotation of RGB, where Y goes along the black-white diagonal of the RGB cube. In Yxy you get two true chromaticity channels. I don’t know what the difference is for your application, but if working in XYZ produces good results, then great! It is cheaper to convert from RGB to XYZ after all. :)
